# Integration Over Spherical Triangle and Change of Variable

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let $T$ denote a spherical triangle on the unit sphere, defined by vertices $u,v,$ and $w$.

Let $\triangle$ denote a triangle. This could be the triangle defined by $u,v,w$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ or the reference triangle $(0,0), (0,1), (1,0)$ or any other choice. You pick.

Here is what I would like to do: For a function $f: \triangle \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,  write the integration over $\triangle$ in terms of T
$$
\int_{\triangle } f(x) dx = \int_{T} \cdots dT
$$

The issue I have run into is that my change of variable $p:T \rightarrow \triangle$ result in something like 
$$
 \int_{T} f(p(y))|Dp(y)|dy
$$ 
but has a Jacobian determinant of zero...I imagine this has to due with the fact that we are working a surfaces contained in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Do you not really want to start with a function $f$ on the *spherical* triangle? You then need to parametrize the spherical triangle $T$ by a map $g\colon \Delta\to T$ and you'll have $$\int_T f(y)dy = \int_\Delta f(g(u))\left\|\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial g}{\partial v}\right\| dudv.$$

Comment: Yes, I want to go from the triangle $\triangle$ to the spherical triangle $T$. I have already done what you have said. Essentially, I have taken the spherical triangle to the standard triangle; done some work on the standard triangle; and am not looking to push it back to the spherical triangle.

Comment: You need to use the cross product as I wrote. The change of variables formula you wrote down only works for a mapping from $n$ dimensions to $n$ dimensions.

Comment: Okay, I see what you are saying. In the map you have above is from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$. So if I am going the other direction,  I have $p:T \rightarrow \triangle$, is from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then p is a function of three variables $x,y,$ and $z$. I get partial derivative $\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}$,$\frac{\partial p}{\partial y}$, $\frac{\partial p}{\partial z}$. How do we employ the  cross product with these?

Comment: No, do not go the other way. Integrals pull back naturally; they don't push forward the way you're trying to do.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is what is commonly done for obtain error estimates in finite element analysis. See affine equivalent finite elements or isoparmetric finite elements. However, the is usually not a dimension.

Comment: Usually something like$$\|err\|_{L^2(T)} \le c\|f\|_{L^2(\triangle)} \le c\|f\|_{L^2(T)}$$. Is it possible to go the other way?

Comment: The only plausible way to go the other way is to have a natural coordinate system (say, spherical coordinates) on the sphere and write down the map $p(\phi,\theta)=(u,v)$. In practice this is *very* hard to do, and, for a general spherical triangle, the region in $(\phi,\theta)$ space will be very awkward.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thank you very much.